# Match digits but exclude digits within square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I'm using PHP. I have the following type of strings:

```
3-5
8[4]-10
14-21[5]
1[5]-12[2]
```

I'm trying to figure out a regex to **capture** only the digits before the square brackets and **exclude the digits** (and the brackets) **inside the square brackets** so that the resulting strings would simply be:

```
3-5
8-10
14-21
1-12
```

After many temptatives I don't understand how to write a regex that excludes matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$bracketsRemoved = preg_replace('/\[\d+\]/', '', $numbersWithBrackets);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `preg_replace()` to get rid of those brackets.

```
// The string
$bracketedString = '19-4[5]';

// Remove brackets
$bracketless = preg_replace('/\[\d+\]/', '', $bracketedString);

/.../ - The regexp
\[ - The escaped opening bracket
\d+ - Numeric values
\] - The escaped closing bracket
```

#### Resource

- [preg_replace() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)